# Normalizer of sub Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra and $H$ be a sub Lie algebra of $L$ for which equals its own normalizer, i.e. $N_L(H) = H$.

Let  $L_1$ be another subalgebra of $L$.

Is it true in general that $L_1 \cap H$ equals its own normalizer, i.e. $N_{L_1}(L_1 \cap H) = L_1 \cap H$?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true; for example, $L_1 \cap H$ could be trivial, in which case $N_{L_1}(L_1 \cap H) = L_1$.